# SystemError: Parent module 'setuptools' not loaded, cannot perform relative import, jupyterhub

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, setuptools, jupyterhub

I am running juypterhub and all my kernels are unable to restart although terminals are just working fine. I went through some other answers and downgraded `setup tools` to `49.3.0` but still my kernels are unable to restart.

The error on the server is:

> SystemError: Parent module 'setuptools' not loaded, cannot perform
> relative import

```
Python - 3.5.2
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this temporary workaround. Run this in terminal

`export SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib`